# Use mapbox for rendering inside pixi-js or any other webgl/canvas framework?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I love the styling options provided by mapbox and need to know if there is any way I can use their map api for a game I am writing.

I dont think I can make any use of a fully finished solution that just loads the map into a container element (mapbox-gl-js) but rather would need image data etc. to use myself in a different engine.

Is this even possible with mapbox? How would I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was looking in the wrong place. Mapbox has its "static" api which allows to fetch the tiles as images directly without rendering it interactively.

So for anyone looking to use mapbox customly then make sure too check out their static api over at: https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/#static